# reference request “A measure-theoretic approach to Malliavin calculus”

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-calculus

Apart from citations all over the internet, the following paper appears to be off-the-grid.

K. Itô, A measure-theoretic approach to Malliavin calculus, in 'New Trends in Stochastic Analysis', Proc. Taniguchi Symposium, Sept. 1994, Charingworth, (eds. K. D. Elworthy, S. Kusuoka and l. Shigekawa), World Scientific, 1997
Does there exist any electronic copy of the article? Or does anyone have a physical copy that they are comfortable with scanning/sharing?

Comment: yes, there is an electronic copy, which is sold by World Scientific, https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/9789814530491#page=231